# HTML5 document and iFrame with end tag breaks within Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe

Why does this code break this page on chrome.  It seems that the rest of the content won't render if I self close the iframe tag.  If I add start iframe tag and  end iframe tag, it doesn't do this.

```
<body>
  <hr />
  <div> 
  <iframe src="https://www.posttestserver.com/"             
         style="width:400px; height: 400px"
         border="0"
         frameborder="0"/>
  </div>  
  <br />
  <div>   
  <iframe src="https://www.posttestserver.com/"    
         scrolling="no"
         border="0"
         frameborder="0"
         style="width:200px; height: 200px"
         />
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ya5rhm2/

Comment: You haven't self-closed the iframe tag. You've put a `/` at the end of the start tag. HTML doesn't have self-closing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, and after looking at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp) page, only empty HTML elements such as BR or IMG can be closed with /> rather than a full closing tag.